# Determinant of $ A^{-1}B (A^{-1})^{T} $ is equal to the determinant of B.

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

In the solution to one of the questions I am attempting it says, $$\det{(A^{-1}B (A^{-1})^{T})} = \det B $$

where A is a lower triangular matrix and B is a diagonal matrix.

Could someone explain why this hold?

Comment: What is the meaning of $'$?

Comment: It is not true in general, if $'$ means transpose...

Comment: Do you know the determinant of $A$?

Comment: Yes, ' means transpose.

Comment: $$
\det(A^{-1}B(A^{-1})^T) = \det A^{-1}\det B \det (A^{-1})^T = (\det A^{-1})^2\det B = \det B /( \det A)^2
$$

Comment: Most probably you have a mistake in your question and it should be $\;A\;$ either in the first o in the third position, meaning: either you have $$\det(AB(A^{-1})^t\;$$ or else you have $\;\det(A^{-1}BA^t)\;$ . If you *actually* have what you wrote then thye claim is false, as caverac's comment above shows.

Comment: @DonAntonio Another option is that $A$ might have $1$'s on the diagonal.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Indeed, yet I understand the question is talking about **general** matrices with the given conditions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is *ONLY* true if $\det(B)=0$ or $\det(A)=\pm 1$.

Observe that since the determinant is multiplicative $(\det(CD)=\det(C)\det(D))$,
$$
\det(A^{-1}B(A^{-1})^T)=\det(A^{-1})\det(B)\det((A^{-1})^T).
$$

Since $\det(C^T)=\det(C)$, this can be simplified to
$$
\det(A^{-1})\det(B)\det((A^{-1})^T)=\det(A^{-1})\det(B)\det(A^{-1}).
$$

Finally, since $\det(C^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(C)}$, we can further simplify to get
$$
\det(A^{-1})\det(B)\det(A^{-1})=\frac{\det(B)}{\det(A)^2}.
$$

For this to equal $\det(B)$, either $\det(B)=0$ or $\det(A)^2=1$.